# Unlimited x-repeat and unlimited scroll of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question that's been bothering me some time.

Suppose I have a couple of `div`'s stacked vertically. Let's say I have 5 of them. What I want is for thos 5 `div`'s to repeat (like with `CSS`, `background-repeat:repeat-y`).

This website has what I mean: https://duroc.ma. You can drag the page, and the contents seem to repeat endlessly. Although it's in the `x` and `y` direction, I just want the `y` direction to do that and to be able to `scroll`, instead of `dragging`.

Now, I know this can be done with `jQuery`, hence the choice for this category. I have really been looking for ages, but all I find is the '`endless scroll`' principle, meaning you can keep scrolling down for new content instead of moving to the next page.

Can someone please give me an indication of what I need to do? Or at least a starting point to move me in the right direction?

Thanks! Cheers

Comment: sounds more like a vertical carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Try a solution with JavaScript. My example works with scroll down only, you can easily update it with scroll up if needed.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener('scroll', endlessScroll);

function endlessScroll() {
  var height = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    height += parent.children[i].clientHeight;
  }
  var firstChild = parent.firstElementChild;
  if (parent.scrollTop >= height - parent.clientHeight) {
    parent.appendChild(firstChild);
    parent.scrollTop -= firstChild.clientHeight;
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent div {
  height: 150px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Update: now it works in all browsers.

Comment: @J.Klaassen, I noticed this solution works well only in Chrome, and need to be improved for other browsers.